# NSMutableArray doesn't get populated on view's first appearance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using the Dropbox SDK to fill an array `filePaths`.
However the array is only filled the second time I open the corresponding view. When I open the view for the first time, the array is empty.

Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks in advance!

```
//  DropboxFileViewController.m

#import "DropboxFileViewController.h"
#import "DropboxViewController.h"
#import "DropboxSDK.h"
#import <stdlib.h>


@interface DropboxFileViewController () <DBRestClientDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, readonly) DBRestClient* restClient;

@end


@implementation DropboxFileViewController
@synthesize dropboxFileView;
@synthesize filePaths;



- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    //NSArray* validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pdf", @"docx", @"doc", nil];
    NSMutableArray* newDropboxFilePaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {
        //NSString* extension = [[child.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];
        //if (!child.isDirectory && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension] != NSNotFound) {
            [newDropboxFilePaths addObject:child.path];
        //}
    }

    [filePaths release];
    filePaths = newDropboxFilePaths;
}



/*- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}*/

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

/*
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];


}

- (DBRestClient*)restClient {
    if (restClient == nil) {
        restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [dropboxFileView reloadData];

}

/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [filePaths count];
    //NSLog(@"deze shit wordt geinvoked vriend");

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...


    //NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [filePaths objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: try to reload table after you downloaded the data, i think the data isent downloaded in viewDidAppear. (sorry for my bad spellin)

Comment: Perhaps you can delete unrelated portions of code next time. Minimal examples are preferred.

Comment: What is a DBRestClient? I've just started with Dropbox and although I have been working on tutorials I haven't entirely understood the dbrestclient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your observation might be wrong. 
I guess DBRestClient does its work in another thread. And shortly after you've left viewWillAppear the tableview gets its data. And at this time the DBRestClient isn't finished.

To fix this simply reload the tableview when you get the data

Append `[dropboxFileView reloadData];` to `- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata`